# Questions about $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^\lambda (x + 4)} \, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, residue-calculus

Questions about

$$I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^\lambda (x + 4)} \, \mathrm{d}x = \pi4^{-\lambda}. $$

The exact solution can be found in Saff/Snider(p349) for $\lambda = 1/2$. I am using $\lambda$ because the next example $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^\lambda (x - 4)} \, \mathrm{d}x$ has many steps similar to this.

Here are my questions

1. They used a branch cut on $(0,2\pi]$ which they called *principal branch* even though the book defines *principal* to mean $(-\pi,\pi].$ Why is it called principal for $(0,2\pi]$?
2. For the pacman contour, here it where it got me. I know in the limiting as $\rho \to \infty, \epsilon \to 0$, the integral will coincide with the real integral, but to come up with this? When I look at the paceman contour, it feels like we are "deleting" the region of integration.
3. These branch cuts are just chosen arbitrary to make our contours convenient right? So why can't I choose the semi-indented region? [image]
4. I actually tried to use the contour above and found that on $x = -4$, I got

   $$ \lim_{\delta \to 0} \int_{S_\delta} \frac{1}{-\sqrt{z}(z+4)} \, \mathrm{d}z = -\pi i \, \underset{z=-4}{\operatorname{Res}} = \frac{-\pi i}{\pm 2i} = - \frac{\pi}{2}$$

   indicating there probably is an issue with my method. But I'd argue that since we are above the $y-$axis, we take $+2$ and hence $-\pi/2$.
5. On $[-\delta - 4, -\epsilon]\cup [-\rho,-4-\delta]$, $\sqrt{x} := -\sqrt{x}$. But one of them go to zero and the other gives $\int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{1}{-\sqrt{x}(x+4)} \, \mathrm{d}x$. Eventually I got to

   $$2I - \frac{\pi}{2} = 0 \qquad \implies \qquad  I = \frac{\pi}{4} \neq \frac{\pi}{2} \stackrel{(\lambda = 1/2)}{=} \pi/4^{-\lambda} $$

   which is "half" the answer (again reject $-2$ because we are on upper circle).
6. I applied the same technique to the next example in the textbook $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^\lambda (x - 4)} \, \mathrm{d}x  $ and yet again, I am missing the other half of the contour. If you are wondering why I keep cutting the negative axis $\{ x = 0, y < 0\}$, it is because I got the idea from $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log x}{x^2 + 1} \, \mathrm{d}x$

Answer (score 3):

**1.** I am not sure either. As far as I know, the term 'principal logarithm' is usually saved for the complex logarithm with imaginary part restricted to $(-\pi, \pi]$.

**2.** The complex integral along the 'mouth' of the pacman will approximate your original integral.

(The beauty in this business is that the choice of branch cut will prevent the integral along both lips from cancelling each other.)

**3-5.** Of course the choice of contour is no more than trick. If we use the semi-circular contour with dents as illustrated in OP's figure, we end up with

$$ \mathrm{PV}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i\sqrt{x}(4-x)} \, \mathrm{d}x -\frac{\pi}{2} + \underbrace{ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(x+4)} \, \mathrm{d}x }_{=I} = 0. $$

Here, $\mathrm{PV}$ means that the integral is understood in Cauchy principal-value sense. Also notice that the integral coming from the negative real axis no longer equals $I$, and this is indeed one disadvantage of OP's contour compared with the pacman contour.

Thankfully, in this case the PV integral is purely imaginary, and so, taking real parts of both sides proves that $I = \pi/2$ for $\lambda = 1/2$. Note that we no longer expect this luck when $\lambda \neq 1/2$. In such case, I would prefer to use pacman contour.

**6.** If $\lambda \in (0, 1)$ and the same computation is performed along the semicircular contour as in OP's figure, we end up with

$$ \mathrm{PV} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{e^{i\pi \lambda} x^{\lambda}(4-x)} - \frac{\pi i}{e^{i\pi\lambda}4^{\lambda}} + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{\lambda}(x+4)} = 0. $$

As mentioned before, the PV integral no longer needs to be purely imaginary. So we need some extra step to extract an answer. By setting $J = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{\lambda}(4-x)}$, we know that both $I$ and $J$ are real and satisfies

$$ e^{-i\pi\lambda} J - e^{i\pi(\frac{1}{2}-\lambda)} \frac{\pi}{4^{\lambda}} + I = 0. $$

Comparing both the real and imaginary parts, we obtain the following system of linear equations

$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
\cos(\pi\lambda) J - \sin(\pi\lambda) \frac{\pi}{4^{\lambda}} + I &=& 0, \\
-\sin(\pi\lambda) J - \cos(\pi\lambda) \frac{\pi}{4^{\lambda}} &=& 0.
\end{array} \right. $$

So it follows that

$$ J = -\frac{\pi}{4^{\lambda}} \cot(\pi\lambda), \qquad I = \frac{\pi}{4^{\lambda} \sin(\pi\lambda)}. $$

Comment: In $\mathrm{PV}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i\sqrt{x}(4-x)}$ how did you get the $i$ in the bottom? on $(-\infty,0)$ the argument is $\pi$ isn't it? It seems like you got $\pi/2$

Comment: @Hawk, Note that, if $\operatorname{Log}$ denotes the complex logarithm with the branch cut on $(0,2\pi]$, then for $a > 0$ we have $$\sqrt{-a}=\exp\bigl(\tfrac{1}{2}\operatorname{Log}(-a)\bigr)=\exp\bigl(\tfrac{1}{2}(\log(a)+i\pi)\bigr)=e^{i\pi/2}e^{\frac{1}{2}\log a}=i\sqrt{a}. $$ For example, we get $\sqrt{-4}=2i$ and so forth.

Comment: Ah the division by $2$. Well let me try that out first myself to see if I can fix that mistake and I read the rest, but I am still taking the cut on $(-\pi2/,3\pi/2]$ Does it actually matter on the $)$ and $]$ in the cut? I've seen some books restrict it to open sets completely.

Comment: @Hawk, If you use the upper semicircular contour, then any choice of branch cut containing the region $(0,\pi)$ will make the computation unchanged. For instance, any of the choices $(0, 2\pi]$, $[0, 2\pi)$, $(-\pi, \pi]$, or $(-\pi/2,3\pi/2]$ works.

Comment: How did $(x+4) \to (4-x)$? Shouldn't it be $x+4 \to -(x+4)$ after you switch the limits $(-\infty,0) \to (0,\infty)?$

Comment: @Hawk, It is the change of variable $u = -x$: $$\mathrm{PV}\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{\lambda}(x+4)}=\mathrm{PV}\int_{\infty}^{0}\frac{-\mathrm{d}u}{(-u)^{\lambda}(-u+4)}$$ and this simplifies to the integral mentioned in my answer. But to be honest, this substitution is only used in my answer to identify the argument of this integral, and so, you may leave it as it is, so long as you can correctly identify its argument by other means.

Comment: "Thankfully, in this case the PV integral is purely imaginary" this is under the assumption this part  $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}(4-x)} $ is real right  ? If so how do you know this? Because this integrates purely on the real number line? I am starting to see why my contour fails. Were my other reasoning on the $+2$ on the little semi-circular region $S_\delta$ correct?

Comment: @Hawk, For the integral, that is correct. The Cauchy principal-value in this case is defined as the limit $$\mathrm{PV}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x}(4-x)}=\lim_{\delta\to0^+}\left(\int_{0}^{4-\delta}+\int_{4+\delta}^{\infty}\right), $$ which is clearly real as you suspected. For the second part, I think I am not fully following your reasoning. (Presumably you seem to be asking whether $\sqrt{-4}=2i$ or not, which is indeed correct.) Perhaps it would help if you reflect the correct arguments of $\sqrt{\cdot}$ and so forth.

Comment: Well I mean in $$\lim_{\delta \to 0} \int_{S_\delta} \frac{1}{-\sqrt{z}(z+4)} \, \mathrm{d}z = -\pi i \, \underset{z=-4}{\operatorname{Res}} = \frac{-\pi i}{\pm 2i} = - \frac{\pi}{2}.$$ Isn't the argument still $\pi$? And hence $$\sqrt{-4} = \exp ( 0.5(\log
+ |-4| + i\pi)) = \sqrt{4}e^{i\pi/2} = \pm 2i.$$ Was I correct in reasoning that we choose positive because $S_\delta$ is above the $y = 0?$

Comment: @Hawk, $4e^{i\pi/2}$ is unarguably $2i$ because $e^{i\pi/2}=i$. (The correct sign is already determined by the choice of branch cut of logarithm.) So I am not sure why you are writing $\pm2i$ and trying to identify its sign by other means...

Comment: You mean because $e^{ i\pi/2} = (0 + 1i)$ the argument then fixes it in the first quadrant right? Hence we rule out the symmetric $-2i$ point. Excuse for elementary question.

Comment: @Hawk. That is true. Indeed one of the purposes of fixing the branch cut of logarithm is to make the sign choice unique and explicit. :)

Comment: So I learned my contour won't work. Now as I flipped through the pages to the exercises and most of the integrand has the similar form, there is a complex power $x^\lambda$ of nonifnteger values and a rational with poles either on the real line (limits of integration) or on the negative real axis. It looks to me they all imply me to use pacman contour.

Comment: I am report back to tomorrow.

Comment: @Hawk, As I demonstrated in **part 6**, your contour works for this integral but not in the same way as the pacman contour does. And in many textbook examples, the pacman contour will likely work much smoother than the semicircular one. Perhaps it is best if you know both pros and cons of different choices of contours, but you may first focus on mastering one particular strategy at a time. Good luck :)

Comment: So after doing a few more exercises (like all of them) in the book, I found that the book pretty wants you to use the keyhole region with cut along the nonnegative axis. This appears to be the expectation within the classroom/exam setting.Do I have this correct?

Answer (score 1):

**Easier with Gamma function**
Letting $4y=x$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^\lambda(x+4)} d x & =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(4 y)^\lambda(y+1)} d y \\
& =\frac{1}{4^\lambda} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{y^{-\lambda}}{y+1} d y \\
& =\frac{1}{4^\lambda} B(-\lambda+1, \lambda) \\
& =\frac{\pi}{4^\lambda \sin (\pi \lambda)} \quad \text { (By Reflection Property) }
\end{aligned}
$$